# Angularjs ng-pageslide issue

Tags: angularjs

Demo of my issue here: http://plnkr.co/edit/S6FOPYg3S2Xa2XLdyJmA?p=preview

I am using the Angularjs plugin (https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide) like this:

```
<a pageslide href="#target">Link text</a>

<div id="target">            
    <p>some random content...</p>
    <a id="target-close" href="#">Click to close</a>
</div>
```

Which works great. But for reasons I wont go into I need to have 4 links pointing to the same pageslide div like this:

```
<a pageslide href="#target">Link1 text</a>
<a pageslide href="#target">Link2 text</a>
<a pageslide href="#target">Link3 text</a>
<a pageslide href="#target">Link4 text</a>

<div id="target">            
    <p>some random content...</p>
    <a id="target-close" href="#">Click to close</a>
</div>
```

But when I do this, only link4 has the content of the target div in it. The other 3 links show an empty page slide. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't reference the same target from different links/buttons. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide/issues/26) and also created a [pull request](https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide/pull/27) with a fix. Here is also a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oETTSwPXUEyu5AdfI6Wu?p=preview) with fixed ngPageSlider code.

Comment: @dfsq - Thanks! In your example it appears to be working with both links. Did you fix this issue in your pageslide-directive script?

Comment: Yes, I fixed this issue in my fork branch, and opened pull request. You can wait until it's merged or you can use fixed version.